# Asynchronous image downloader/cache for Monotouch

Tags: image, caching, asynchronous, xamarin.ios

After googling it for a while I could not find a library to use inside of my current Monotouch application.

I would like to know if are there some Monotouch libraries which are able to execute features like:

- Asynchronous image downloader;
- Asynchronous memory/disk image caching;
- Cancel image download support;

When developing with Objective-C I was used to use the well known [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/) library.

If possible I would like to use a library which is in part Xamarin Cross-Platform supported in order to also use it into the Mono For Android version of my current application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We always use the `ImageLoader` in `MonoTouch.Dialog`. It has caching and asynchronous downloading. For cancellation, you will have to handle that yourself, however.

See here: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Utilities/ImageLoader.cs

It is a built-in reference in Xamarin.iOS now, you should be able to find it in the Add Reference dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Also from Xamarin there is: https://github.com/xamarin/prebuilt-apps/blob/master/EmployeeDirectory/EmployeeDirectory/Utilities/ImageDownloader.cs.

While this is far from being complete in my opinion it is a better approach to a crossplatfom solution.